# Is it possible to send a file to a printer with a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, cmd, wmic

How can I use a batch file to send a text file or a .doc or similar, to a printer plugged into the computer through a USB port?

Comment: `c:\> print /d:name_of_printer file_to_print`

Comment: what google does not answer with "print from batch file" ? just type that and you'll have many solutions available

Comment: @MarcB, the printer device to redirect is called `prn`, isn't it?

Comment: @aschipfl: pretty much. but prn is simply the system default printer, and if you've got multiple printers, you may want to target one specifically, which is why there's `print`.

Comment: @MarcB, I misinterpreted your comment (maybe it was too late... ;-)), I read the `>` as redirection operator rather than part of the command prompt...

Answer (score 4):

Also to get the printer name:

```vb
wmic printer get name /value | findstr Name
```

It will list all printers like:

```vb
Name=PDF
Name=Microsoft XPS Document Writer
Name=Fax
```

And if you know part of the name, you may include it in a variable dynamically with `FOR`.

```vb
@echo off

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
    'wmic printer get name /value ^| findstr PartOfThePrinterName'
) do (
    set "printer_name=%%a"
)

REM Also you can remove the FOR command if you want to set the variable as static.
REM ie. "set printer_name=MyPrinterName"

print filename.txt /D:"%printer_name%"

exit /b 0
```

note the double quotes and no white space after `/D:` to be sure it get the right printer.

**Another method** is to set the default printer and print the document through the notepad.

```vb
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "%printer_name%"
start /min notepad /P filename.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PRINT` command like below to print `ASCII files`. Use `print /?` in command prompt to know more about the command. Here, `/D` is the switch fr device name since by default it's LPT1.

```
PRINT filename.txt /D:<printer_name>
```

Also, see this [Article](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php) for much more information on printing PDF's etc.

Comment: I tried it but i get the console displaying the text "C:\Python27> print message.txt /D: Canon Inkjet MP760 Series" infinite times. am I missing something?

Comment: @NicholasAnderson the printer name should be inside double quotes

Comment: @Paul I have the printer name in double quotes but it is still doing the same thing. `print message.txt /D: "Canon Inkjet MP760 Series"` [what it looks like](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z7rxmk7esgrodbq/Capture3.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Don't put space, do this like: `echo Test the print command>_printing.txt &print _printing.txt /D:"Canon Inkjet MP760 Series"`

Comment: @Paul I get the error: "Unable to initialize device Canon Inkjet MP760 Series" Could the printer have a problem?

Comment: @NicholasAnderson I get this issue too but I don't know how to resolve it. You should ask in http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a native way, with anything required, but only ASCII, and has to open a window:

```
notepad /P file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to print *.doc and *.xls using libreoffice, like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" -p "YourFilePAth"
```