# Write into thermal printer under windows

Tags: c++

To print a receipt under Linux system I'm using this code:

```
char *buff
fd = open("/dev/usb/lp0", O_RDWR);
if(!write(fd, buff, len)) return 0;
```

Ever device under Linux system is a file, we can open it and write data without problem.

My question is about windows system using c++ language.

Comment: You shouldn't in practice use that on Linux; better `popen("lp", "w")`

Comment: under windows you will have to use the printing apis, msdn should have docs on it

Comment: On Windows you can [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153)(NULL, "print", "receipt1234.txt", "", "C:\\receipts")

Comment: im going to test popen("lp", "w") wish it will be a portable routine ? about shellExecute i dont have any idea how it works !

Comment: It is not different on Windows.  But the odds that the device driver provides "LPT1" are not that great, parallel printers have gone the way of the dodo a long time ago.  If the programming manual does not provide hints then give the manufacturer a call.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no "portable" way to access the printer. Each operating system has its own way(s), and you will need to write separate code for each. `#ifdef`, here we come.

Comment: Is there a link where i can find some c++ examples ? i mean for windows system.

Comment: @KaiIskratsch you don't have to. In DOS era people simply use [`copy file.txt LPT1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#DOS.2C_TOS.2C_OS.2F2.2C_and_Windows). In modern Windows there are various other options like the [`print` command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32595421/995714). A similar way can be used if you map the thermal printer to a device like that